# What am I doing wrong with my FetchedResultsController that it gives me the warning for setting its delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have the following code:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (!_fetchedResultsController) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ArticleInfo" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        request.entity = entity;

        NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"timeStamp" ascending:NO];
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptor];

        request.fetchBatchSize = 20;

        NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"];
        _fetchedResultsController = fetchedResultsController;
        _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    }

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

It reports this error back:

> Assigning to 'id' from
>   incompatible type 'RootViewController *const __strong'

What exactly am I doing wrong to cause that?

Comment: Do your class implement the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate protocol?

Comment: You just need to add <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate> to your .h file to silence that warning.

Comment: Could one of you make that the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let the compiler know that your class conforms to the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol.

You can do this by adding it to your `.h` file

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
```

or possibly more preferable add it to a class extension. So in your `.m` file

```
@interface RootViewController () <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
```

The reasoning why this could be considered as being a little better is that it's better information hiding - no other class needs to know that `RootViewController` conforms to the `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate` protocol so why make it publicly visible?